# Pygame: Can't move player when main menu function added

Tags: python, pygame

I'm still working on a game in Pygame. I've got the gameplay to work, I just want to make a main menu function so when a button is pressed, the game starts.

When I added in the main menu, and edited the game loop, I was unable to move the player sprite, and the game wouldn't close when I press the "X out" button (it goes irresponsive(this didn't happen before)).

This didn't happen originally.

And there's no traceback.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import time
import itertools
import os

pygame.init()
SCREENWIDTH = 1000
SCREENHEIGHT = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT])
screen.fill((255, 123, 67))
screen.blit(pygame.image.load("Backgrounds/mainmenu.png"), (0, 0))

background = screen.copy()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mi_level = False

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("Sprites/lee.png")

    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = Player.sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(445, 550))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        self.lives = 50
        self.score = 0
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-20, -30)
    def update(self):
        self.pos = self.rect.center
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 3
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += dist
            self.hitbox.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= dist
            self.hitbox.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += dist
            self.hitbox.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= dist
            self.hitbox.x -= dist

        if self.rect.right > SCREENWIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREENWIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > SCREENHEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREENHEIGHT
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50

        self.hitbox.center = self.pos
        if self.lives <= 0:
            screen.blit(pygame.image.load("gameover.png"), (0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            time.sleep(5)
            os._exit(0)
            pygame.quit()
            stageon = False
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(sprites)

def main():
    running = True
    mi_level = False
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("Backgrounds/mainmenu.png"), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT or running == False:
                time.sleep(1)
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                return
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 204, 204), (690, 110, 700, 135), 0)
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and pygame.Rect(690, 110, 880, 165).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            screen.fill((255, 123, 67))
            screen.blit(pygame.image.load("Backgrounds/mi_level.png"), (0, 50))
            pygame.display.flip
            background = screen.copy()
            mi_level = True
        pygame.display.update()            
        while mi_level:
            sprites.update()

            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            sprites.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.update()

            clock.tick(100)
            if mi_level == False:
                return
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT or running == False:
                time.sleep(1)
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wonder what amateur mistake I've made this time...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a game loop. There is not any need of "nested" game loops:

<s>`while mi_level:`</s>

A simple `if` statement, which evaluates if the game is started is sufficient:

```py
if mi_level:
    # []...]
```

Note, in your code in the inner loops, the events haven't been evaluated, because [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) is missing. This causes that the `pygame.QUIT` event wasn't handled any more and the window didn't close and react as intended.

See the changes to the main loop:

```py
def main():
    running = True
    mi_level = False
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("Backgrounds/mainmenu.png"), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT or running == False:
                time.sleep(1)
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                return
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 204, 204), (690, 110, 700, 135), 0)
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and pygame.Rect(690, 110, 880, 165).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            screen.fill((255, 123, 67))
            screen.blit(pygame.image.load("Backgrounds/mi_level.png"), (0, 50))
            pygame.display.flip()
            background = screen.copy()
            mi_level = True

        if mi_level:
            sprites.update()
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            sprites.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(100)
        pygame.display.update()
```